# Can you check compatibility of Linear Congruences with non-coprime moduli before simplifying?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

Given a pair of linear congruences of the form below where the $m_i$ are not necessarily coprime.
$$a_1 x \equiv b_1 \pmod{m_1}$$
$$a_2 x \equiv b_2 \pmod{m_2}$$

I know that if the $a_1 = a_2 = 1$, then we can check if congruences are compatible by checking if,
$$ a_1 = a_2 \pmod{gcd(m_2, m_2)}$$

However, I am wondering if there is a way to check compatibility of two congruences without first finding the inverses of $a_1$ and $a_2$ to simplify the system to the form of,

$$x \equiv a_1^{-1} b_1 \pmod{m_1}$$
$$x \equiv a_2^{-1} b_2 \pmod{m_2}$$

I am hoping to avoid the computational cost of computing an inverse if the equations are not compatible.

Comment: See the Theorem in the linked dupe.

Comment: Thank you! Although not mentioned, I assume that theorem is true even if $m_1$ and $m_2$ are not coprime?

Comment: Yes,  the  theorem assumes only all $(a_i,m_i)=1$ (which can always be achieved by cancelling $\,(a_i,m_i)\,$ from  $\,a_i,b_i,m_i\,$ (it must divide $b_i$ if it is solvable).